# How to define Foreign Key without having navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I have following classes:

```
public class Company
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public CompanyDetail CompanyDetail { get; set; }  // This is optional
}

public class CompanyDetail
{

    public Guid Company_Id { get; set; }  // This supposed to be PK and the FK to Company

    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string WebSite { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

I don't need to navigate from CompanyDetail to Company so I don't have navigation property.

A Company may have CompanyDetail but it is not required.

The expected design is having a table named CompanyDetail and the Company_Id is the PK as well as FK (to Company table)

When I create the model, I receive following error:

> EntityType 'CompanyDetail' has no key defined. Define the key for this
>   EntityType. CompanyDetails: EntityType: EntitySet 'CompanyDetails' is
>   based on type 'CompanyDetail' that has no keys defined.

I need to how I can resolve the issue using Fluent API or Data Annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define [Key] for CompanyDetail

try

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual CompanyDetail CompanyDetail { get; set; }  // This is optional
}

public class CompanyDetail
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Company_Id { get; set; } 

}

...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
        .HasOptional<CompanyDetail>(u => u.CompanyDetail)
```